# Extracting text (Hindi Language) from a Pdf file in iOS app.

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pdf-parsing

I see so many apps that actually have stories in hindi language, but i wonder that how does that work.

Is there any way that i can parse hindi pdf or doc file?

Flexible to have the solution in Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: If its a duplicate or basic question than please guide me to the question which is  already present or just guide me the links where i can find any information regarding this.